# In a Hugo partial template, how do I access secondary/additional parameters?

Tags: go, go-templates, hugo

Say I have `{{ partial "li.html" $test $root.Data.Term }}`.

With this I can can access the first parameter, or `$test`, by simply refering to `.` within the `li.html` template, but how do I access the second or additional parameter (`$root.Data.Term`) from within the same template?

Comment: Try `{{ partial "li.html" (dict "test" $test "Term" $root.Data.Term ) }}`, then access them with `.test` and `.Term`. Based-on: [https://gohugo.io/functions/dict/](https://gohugo.io/functions/dict/)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would suggest using the hugo **dict** function. It allows you to use key/value pairs to pass information. The [documentation](https://gohugo.io/functions/dict/) states that for your use case.

```
{{ partial "yourPartial" (dict "test" "yourTestData" "term" "yourTerm") }}
```

You can then access the values by just using **{{ .test }}** and **{{ .term }}**.

Alternatively you can use the [scratch](https://gohugo.io/functions/scratch/) function, which is a more "global" approach.